# Illegal string offset value in PHP - only two fields fail

Tags: php

I have two scripts, one which scrubs some HTML output from my system and returns an array of data (tournaments in this example).

When I `var_dump` this array you get the following output.

```
array(66) {
 [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(14) "2 January 2017"
    ["tournament"]=>
    string(43) "Brisbane International presented by Suncorp"
    ["surface"]=>
    string(10) "Hard Court"
    ["venue"]=>
    string(8) "Brisbane"
  }
 [1]=>
  array(4) {
   ["date"]=>
   string(14) "2 January 2017"
   ["tournament"]=>
   string(19) "Aircel Chennai Open"
   ["surface"]=>
   string(10) "Hard Court"
   ["venue"]=>
   string(7) "Chennai"
  }
```

Here is the script that gets that data

```
function processTournamentHTML($url) {
    $domOb = new DomDocument();
    $html = $domOb->loadHTMLFile($url);
    $domOb->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 
    $container = $domOb->getElementsByTagName('tr'); 

    $tournaments = array(); // BLANK ARRAY TO POPULATE

    // PROCESS THE TOURNAMENT HTML INTO A PHP ARRAY
    foreach($container as $row) {
        $items = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
        $tournaments[] = array(
            "date" => $items->item(0)->nodeValue,
            "tournament" => $items->item(1)->nodeValue,
            "surface" => $items->item(2)->nodeValue,
            "venue" => $items->item(3)->nodeValue
        ); 
    }
    echo "Processing the following URL: " . $url;
    return $tournaments;
}
```

And the script that inserts said data into my DB (all sample data).

```
function processTournaments($tournaments, $tour) {
    // OPEN CONNECTION
    $conn = mysqli_connect("test", "test", "test", "test");

    foreach($tournaments as $tournament) {
        $date = $tournament["date"];
        $tournament = $tournament["tournament"];
        $surface = $tournament["surface"];
        $venue = $tournament["venue"];          
        $sql = "INSERT INTO data_table (date, tournament, surface, venue, tour) VALUES ($date, $tournament, $surface, $venue, $tour)";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
    // CLOSE DB CONNECTION
    mysqli_close($conn);
    return "Finished processing for " . $tour;
}
```

I run my code in URL/TO/FILE.php

```
$tournaments = processTournamentHTML($url);
processTournaments($tournaments, "tournament_code");
```

As you can see my sample data has `66` records and I get these errors 66 times:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'surface' in URL/TO/FILE.PHP on line 47

Warning: Illegal string offset 'venue' in URL/TO/FILE.PHP on line 48
```

And the sample HTML being processed

```
<tr>
<td rowspan="3" width="133">2 January 2017</td>
<td width="294">Brisbane International presented by Suncorp</td>
<td width="90">Hard Court</td>
<td width="121">Brisbane</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3" width="133">2 January 2017</td>
<td width="294">Shenzhen Open</td>
<td width="90">Hard Court</td>
<td width="121">Shenzhen</td>
</tr>
```

**SOLVED**

I eventually solved this because I was using the following code:

```
foreach($tournaments as $tournament) {
  $date = $tournament["date"];
  $tournament = $tournament["tournament"]; // WHEN YOU SEE IT
  $surface = $tournament["surface"];
  $venue = $tournament["venue"];
}
```

When you see it, its so annoying. I was using `$tournament` as a variable inside my foreach and it was overwriting the `$tournament` index I was on. -_-

Comment: does the $url that your fetching the DOM form have the required 3 and 4th table cells?

Comment: yes - I will post above the contents, apologies.

Comment: @dsadnick amended

Answer (score 0):

You have

`"surface" => $items->item(2)->nodeValue,
 "venue" => $items->item(3)->nodeValue`

but you dont have anything in the position item[2] and item[3] which you can see from your var dump

```
array(66) {
[0]=>
array(4) {
["date"]=>
string(14) "2 January 2017"
["tournament"]=>
string(43) "Brisbane International presented by Suncorp"
["surface"]=>
string(10) "Hard Court"
["venue"]=>
string(8) "Brisbane"
}
[1]=>
array(4) {
["date"]=>
string(14) "2 January 2017"
["tournament"]=>
string(19) "Aircel Chennai Open"
["surface"]=>
string(10) "Hard Court"
["venue"]=>
string(7) "Chennai"
}
```

In the above array you have only two indexes. There is no [2] and [3]

Comment: I think you've taken it out of context. The `66` is the amount of table rows and thus amounts as `66 tournaments` the `[0]` and `[1]` you see above an instance of a `tournament` which is an array of data within the tournaments array.

the item(2) and item(3) and the third and fourth table cell in the HTML mark up.